# PHP: preg_match_all - Couldn't write a working RegEx

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I have for example a string `\try Tester234` where I want to find the Word (partially with digits)
(RegEx => `(\w|\d)`) after the `\try`.
But a `var_dump($match)` outputs that:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      empty
  1 => 
    array
      empty
```

---

```
preg_match_all('/^\\try ((\d|\w)*)/i', "\try Tester", $match);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need four backslashes to insert a literal one in a regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/^\\\\block ((\d|\w)*)/i', "\block Tester", $match);
```

which is maybe better written like this:

```
preg_match_all('/^\\\\block (\w+)/i', "\block Tester", $match);
```

Comment: @SilentGhost: indeed, forgot `\w` includes digits, thanks for pointing that out.